What content types would you find useful in a commercial UX/UI portfolio template?
Overview 
I am working my personal CMS portfolio site which I plan to provide as a free resource for  designers. The CMS is set up with the idea that you create a range of content for a detailed personal case study or a more image focused agency style presentation. The site theme can be edited with options to define colors, layout and animation styles.
I understand you can create case studies with a standard text and image blog format, I am looking to provide more specific UI UX focused components to provide a more polished result.
If you have any experience with existing templates what is missing?
What elements would you find usefully to fill out case study content? 
So far I have included these content blocks:

Rich-text- standard text block with support for inline images and text formatting.
Image - supports single or multiple images as grid and caption description for each. You can also define max container width.
Hot spot image - highlight key areas of an image and provide text description.
Video - full width video used for agency style hero reel.
Block-quote - highlight key content.
List - highlight key findings from research or testing.
Results - highlight project impact / KPI


Links or files that refer back to the actual website (of the prototypes designed) or design file (e.g. Figma file) that reviewers can go to or download could be useful.
Summary blocks of the types of skills you used in the project, the types of tools and the types of assets created could also be useful.
